# Can you Get the "About me" feature on Discord bot's? (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have recently been seeing bots that have the new "about me" feature!
But, I can't Out how to use this on a Discord.py bot.
I've read the discord.py documentation to see if there was anything about it, but I found no answer to if you can.

But I found a bot that had the "about me" feature, But it also said it was made using Discord.py
[image: (Click this hyperlink for the image)]

Does anyone know how you would enable this?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack! You can't get the `about me` for discord.py yet, you have to wait until v2.0. You can get updates on it in the official `discord.py` support server though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can!
Go to your bot's page in the developer portal!
Then go to the general information tab

https://i.stack.imgur.com/33VQT.png

Right under this, you can type out your bot's description and it will show up in the about me page

For example, I did this with my bot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZzgA.png