# discord.py get user "about me" section

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was wondering if it was possible using discord.py to get the "about me" section of a given user. I did not find anything in the API documentation so I'm asking here to be sure.

Comment: I think this should help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68465238/can-you-get-the-about-me-feature-on-discord-bots-discord-py/

Comment: I don't believe that the discord.py api has implemented it yet but it should soon

Answer (score 3):

If i'm reading your question correctly, you need your bot to access a given users bio / profile / "about me", not apply an "about me" to your bot.  The short answer is, its not available in the discord API at this time because the API team thinks there are privacy concerns:

https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/3095#issuecomment-868817186

Answer (score -2):

Yeah just add a description to the bot in [DEV portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Go to Applications > Choose your Application

Then go to Bots Section and Description ( Enter want you want in the About Me here )

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30458582)

Comment: yeah ok I did it , I thought of it but didn't had time